# Android Listview Horizontal

Tags: java, android, listview

My xml (lvlayout.xml) layout for a listview is currently like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/busnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/servdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#23cf34" />
```

I populate the listview via a simplecursor adapter like this:

```
dueAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(main.this, R.layout.lvlayout,
            dueBusesCursor, columnsdue, to);
    dueListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    dueListView.setAdapter(dueAdapter);
```

How can I make the listviews horizontal so that the user scrolls sideways ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView does not support the horizontal mode. The closest thing to a horizontal ListView is Gallery.

Comment: That is true. But sadly the behaviour of Gallery is quite different from ListView. I mean the centering. I can set to always select the second item. But it is impossible to get stuff like fill from left or from right. The good stuff that is in ListView :(. And extending Gallery does not work well enough. To copy the gallery code to make it work as a ListView does not work either :(.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ViewPager :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html